# Saving Powerpoint as PDF using excel VBA

Tags: vba, pdf, powerpoint, save-as

I am getting a "runtime error '13' type mismatch" error message when I am trying to run the code below. It is providing an error on the 6th line of code where I am trying to export as fixed format.

```
Sub Button5_Click()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="P:\SFO-CSIM-Dept\Risk-Mgmt\SubAdvised\20" & Range("F14").Value & "\InvRisk_" & Range("F15").Value & "_USE4L_Risk Report_" & Range("F14").Value & ".xlsm"

 Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

 PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.SaveAs FileName:="P:\SFO-CSIM-Dept\Risk-Mgmt\SubAdvised\20" & Range("F14").Value & "\InvRisk_" & Range("F15").Value & "_USE4L_Risk Report_" & Range("F14").Value & ".pptx"

 PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Name & ".pdf", ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint

 Application.DisplayAlerts = True 

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: When you get that message and click on the Debug button, one line will be highlighted. Which one?

Comment: this line:

 PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Name & ".pdf", ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint

Comment: You need to instruct PowerPoint app to open the pptx first. And if PowerPoint not running already, you need to Create it.

Comment: it is already open and created when I run this macro

Comment: It's not raising an error in PowerPoint. In Excel, in Tools>References, have you added Microsoft PowerPoint Object Library as a reference? If not, you'll have to use numeric values instead of ppFixedFormatTypePDF and ppFixedFormatIntentPrint.

Comment: I checked Microsoft PowerPoint 15.0 Object Library. It is still providing the same error. I also tried converting ppFixedFormatTypePDF and ppFixedFormatIntentPrint to value of 2 by using const ppFixtedFormatTypePDF = 2. Neither are working.

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out there is a bug using the export routine for powerpoint within excel vba, it works if you do this instead, PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.SaveAs filename, ppSaveAsPDF