# Save PPT as pdf using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, powerpoint

I've copied charts from excel to ppt and rearranged them in the slides. Now I'd like to save as pdf.
My main problem is that it gives me an error "variable not defined" (ppFixedFormatTypePDF is highlighted)
I've tried different options but none of them works.
I know that the two loops could be merged to one, but I do not have the skills to do so. If you have an easy solution to this problem as well it is appreciated
Thank you!

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyToPPT()

Dim PPT As Object
Dim chr
Set PPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
PPT.Visible = True
PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:="H:\VBA Projects\EXC\test.ppt"

Const START_LEFT_POS As Long = 95
Const START_TOP_POS As Long = 5
Const GAP As Long = 5 'gap between charts

Dim LeftPos As Long
LeftPos = START_LEFT_POS

Dim TopPos As Long
TopPos = START_TOP_POS

Dim NextSlideIndex As Long
NextSlideIndex = 2
Dim NextSlideIndex2 As Long
NextSlideIndex2 = 3

PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(2, 3)).Delete
PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Copy
PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste Index:=3

PPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide NextSlideIndex
    
With Sheets("Output")
        Dim ChrtIndex As Long
        For ChrtIndex = 1 To .ChartObjects.Count
            .ChartObjects(ChrtIndex).Chart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
            PPT.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
            With PPT.ActiveWindow.View.slide
                With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
                    .Left = LeftPos
                    .Top = TopPos
                    .Width = 160
                    .Height = 155
                    If ChrtIndex Mod 2 = 1 Then
                        LeftPos = LeftPos + .Width + GAP
                    Else
                        LeftPos = START_LEFT_POS
                        TopPos = TopPos + .Height + GAP
                    End If
                End With
            End With
            If ChrtIndex Mod 4 = 0 Then
                LeftPos = START_LEFT_POS
                TopPos = START_TOP_POS
                NextSlideIndex = NextSlideIndex + 1
                PPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide NextSlideIndex
            End If
        Next ChrtIndex
End With


With Sheets("Uddybet")
        Dim ChrtIndex2 As Long
        For ChrtIndex2 = 1 To .ChartObjects.Count
            .ChartObjects(ChrtIndex2).Chart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
            PPT.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
            With PPT.ActiveWindow.View.slide
                With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
                    .Left = LeftPos
                    .Top = TopPos
                    .Width = 160
                    .Height = 155
                    If ChrtIndex2 Mod 2 = 1 Then
                        LeftPos = LeftPos + .Width + GAP
                    Else
                        LeftPos = START_LEFT_POS
                        TopPos = TopPos + .Height + GAP
                    End If
                End With
            End With
            If ChrtIndex Mod 4 = 0 Then
                LeftPos = START_LEFT_POS
                TopPos = START_TOP_POS
                NextSlideIndex2 = NextSlideIndex2 + 1
                PPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide NextSlideIndex2
            End If
        Next ChrtIndex2
End With

'Save as pdf
Dim dt As String
Dim strPath As String
dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm")

'ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat "H:\VBA Projects\EXC\test_" & dt & ".pdf", ppFixedFormatTypePDF

strPath = "H:\VBA Projects\EXC\test_" & dt & ".pdf"

ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat Path:=strPath, FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF

'Dim dt As String
'dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm")
'        PPT.ExportAsFixedFormat ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & test & dt & ".pdf", ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint

End Sub
```

Comment: You are running from Excel so it doesn't know the enumeration for `PpFixedFormatType`. Try swapping `ppFixedFormatTypePDF` to `2` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppfixedformattype))

Comment: ... or use early binding. Saves you a lot of headaches

Comment: I tried that also. It says "object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: @FrankOlsen The error is on the same line? Will be good if you update your code in the question, it's difficult for people to help without knowing what you did. Think you forgot to have `PPT` at the front too. The entire line should probably read `PPT.ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat strPath, 2`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  Now it gives me: "runtime error type mismatch 13". Is it due to data types that are not matched correctly?

Comment: @FrankOlsen Which line did that error occur? You need to help us help you by giving proper details, not knowing which line is just making us guess especially when you gave alot of code.

Comment: The line you helped me with: PPT.ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat strPath, 2

Comment: @FrankOlsen Turns out there's a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61469705/saving-powerpoint-as-pdf-using-excel-vba), try this line instead: `PPT.ActivePresentation.SaveAs strPath, 32`

Comment: Thank you @RaymondWu! This solved the problem. Have a nice day

Comment: @FrankOlsen I have posted an answer, FYI it is recommended to accept an answer (you can only accept one if there are multiple answers) if it answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61469705/saving-powerpoint-as-pdf-using-excel-vba), there is a bug involving `ExportAsFixedFormat` method when used outside of PowerPoint so the alternative method is to use:

`PPT.ActivePresentation.SaveAs strPath, 32`

Where `32` is the value for `ppSaveAsPDF` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppsaveasfiletype)).